# JSONDecodeError when using for loop with firestore data iterating API request

Tags: python, json, python-requests, google-cloud-firestore

I'm lost as to why this error keeps happening and how to solve it.

I'm trying to take data out of one of my firestore collections, using the ID (which is a stock ticker), and iterating that ID through a for loop to an API that returns a JSON array.

Every time I run this, about a third of the way through I'll get the following error, first showing up as **Error: 404**, then displays the following:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

The script works for the first third of the data, but if I delete items in the collection around where the error is, it doesn't resolve the issue so I don't think it has to do with the item in the doc that it's landed on.

*Am I missing something?*

I tried putting an exception in for the 404 error, but either I implemented it badly, or it didn't solve the problem.

```
import requests
import json
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import firestore
import datetime

cred = credentials.Certificate("./serviceAccountKey.json")
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

db = firestore.client()
doc_ref1 = db.collection(u'Quiver').stream()

for doc in doc_ref1:
    symbol = doc.id
    api_url = "https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/{}/company".format(symbol)
    query_url = api_url
    r = requests.get(query_url)

    if r.status_code != 200: 
        print("Error:", r.status_code)

    if r.status_code == 404: 
        print("Error:", r.status_code)

    json_stock = r.json()

    symbol = json_stock['symbol']
    companyName = json_stock['companyName']
    exchange = json_stock['exchange']
    industry = json_stock['industry']
    website = json_stock['website']
    description = json_stock['description']
    CEO = json_stock['CEO']
    issueType = json_stock['issueType']
    sector = json_stock['sector']
    tags = json_stock['tags']

    updateTime = datetime.datetime.now()

    doc_ref = db.collection(u'Quiver').document(u'{}'.format(symbol))
    doc_ref.set({
        u'symbol':u'{}'.format(symbol),
        u'Company Name':u'{}'.format(companyName),
        u'Exchange':u'{}'.format(exchange),
        u'Industry':u'{}'.format(industry),
        u'Website':u'{}'.format(website),
        u'Description':u'{}'.format(description),
        u'Issue Type':u'{}'.format(issueType),
        u'Sector':u'{}'.format(sector),
        u'Tags':u'{}'.format(tags),
        u'Last Update Time':u'{}'.format(updateTime)
    })

    #docs = doc_ref.get({u'summary'})
    print(symbol)
```

Answer (score 0):

A request for stocks for a company that doesn't exist in the service records returns a `404`.

`print`-ing to stdout when this happens isn't enough to handle this since the response body for non 200 status code isn't valid JSON text.

Depending on your business, you have to either skip non `200` responses, fetch the stock information from another service or log this as a critical issue so that you can apply a policy for companies whose stock information are no longer being offered by the service.

This first option to skip on non `200` responses can be done in the following clause.

```py
if r.status_code != 200: 
    print("Error:", r.status_code)
    continue
```

Comment: Thank you Oluwaferni!! Adding continue to both the if statements did it! It's now iterating through the document. It still prints 404 errors now for certain values, and I'm not sure why that is. Any ideas?

Comment: That is because there are company symbols loaded from firestore that are not available in the API service or are not even valid company symbols

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Thank you very much for your prompt response!